# Filtering a list of objects in Vue without altering the original data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am diving into Vue for the first time and trying to make a simple filter component that takes a data object from an API and filters it.

The code below works but i cant find a way to "reset" the filter without doing another API call, making me think im approaching this wrong.

Is a Show/hide in the DOM better than altering the data object?

HTML

```
<button v-on:click="filterCats('Print')">Print</button>

<div class="list-item" v-for="asset in filteredData">
    <a>{{ asset.title.rendered }}</a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      assets: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterCats: function (cat) {
      var items = this.assets
      var result = {}
      Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
        const item = items[key]
        if (item.cat_names.some(cat_names => cat_names === cat)) {
          result[key] = item
        }
      })
      this.assets = result
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData: function () {
      return this.assets
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is a Show/hide in the DOM better than altering the data object?

Not at all. Altering the data is the "Vue way".

You don't need to modify `assets` to filter it.

The recommended way of doing that is using a [**computed property**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html): you would create a `filteredData` computed property that depends on the `cat` data property. Whenever you change the value of `cat`, the `filteredData` will be recalculated automatically (filtering `this.assets` using the current content of `cat`).

Something like below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      cat: null,
      assets: {
        one: {cat_names: ['Print'], title: {rendered: 'one'}},
        two: {cat_names: ['Two'], title: {rendered: 'two'}},
        three: {cat_names: ['Three'], title: {rendered: 'three'}}
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData: function () {
      if (this.cat == null) { return this.assets; } // no filtering
      var items = this.assets;
      var result = {}
      Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
        const item = items[key]
        if (item.cat_names.some(cat_names => cat_names === this.cat)) {
          result[key] = item
        }
      })
      return result;
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="cat = 'Print'">Print</button>

  <div class="list-item" v-for="asset in filteredData">
      <a>{{ asset.title.rendered }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i see now my original code was overwriting the original object. I was able to combine your solution with my original code to fix!